# A control's event triggers all page controls

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

The situation is as follows, I have several controls on the page and each control has an event in the protected method.

The point is that when selecting a DropDownList, before running its own event, the control fires all the events of the controls on the page.

Anyone have a suggestion?

```
Protected Sub Cod_nivel1_ni1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles cod_nivel1_ni1.PreRender
        Session("cod_nivel1_ni1") = Me.cod_nivel1_ni1.SelectedValue

End Sub

Protected Sub Cod_nivel2_ni2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles cod_nivel2_ni2.PreRender
    Session("cod_nivel2_ni2") = cod_nivel2_ni2.SelectedValue

End Sub

Protected Sub Cod_nivel3_ni3_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles cod_nivel3_ni3.PreRender
    Session("cod_nivel3_ni3") = cod_nivel3_ni3.SelectedValue

End Sub

Protected Sub Cod_sistema_sis_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cod_sistema_sis.SelectedIndexChanged

    Session("cod_sistema_sis") = cod_sistema_sis.SelectedValue

    AtualizarArquivosDataLogPRS()

End Sub

Protected Sub DdlSiteId_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddlSiteId.SelectedIndexChanged
    Session("ddlSiteId") = ddlSiteId.SelectedItem.Text

End Sub


Protected Sub DdlDatsArqMed_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DdlDatsArqMed.SelectedIndexChanged
    Session("DdlDatsArqMed") = DdlDatsArqMed.SelectedValue
    TratamentoDatMed()

End Sub
```

Comment: The event being fired should follow the list here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: PreRender events are fired on each refresh SelectedIndexChanged can be fired when a control is initialized (filled with data) try to put a breakpoint to the handler and look at the stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I have already placed PreRender, SelectIndexChange and even then it triggers all events on the page.

I wanted a solution that would only list the event of the control being currently selected.

I no longer have the patience to look for answers.

Comment: @the_lotus gave you the correct path to resolve your issue. You need to understand the way asp.net works. All the page and controls lifecycle events will be fired in every request plus the event you are interested in. But if you don't have the patience to read and understand how it works you really cannot resolve it correctly. Give it a try and you will see that it is simpler than you thought...

Comment: @the_lotus thanks for the reply, I read the article and I understood correctly, I reorganized the logic of the code and the execution sequence of the controls. Everything working Okay!